# libgdx 2D animation with TexturePacker/Atlas

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to animate a 2D image, I have each of my images cut out into appropriate sizes. However I am not sure how to use the TexturePacker and TextureAtlas to animate them. I looked at the libgdx github tutorial but it does not show how it works. I have each of my seven images in appropriate format such as (image_1,image_2,image_3...etc) as suggested on the tutorial, how do I pack these images and use them with the Atlas? Any code sample would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I figured it out guys I'm actually just suppose to pack it with the TexturePacker tool which I had to download its a separate .jar file from [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/) and then execute this lines of code

```
TextureAtlas atlas;
public Animation<TextureRegion> runningAnimation;

atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("directory/pack.atlas"));
runningAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.033f,atlas.findRegions("running"), PlayMode.LOOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an official [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation) about animation, [TexturePacker+TextureAtlas](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer).

Also, a good [tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2015/02/27/LibGDX-Video-Tutorial-Sprite-Animation.aspx) on animation for Libgdx

And [tutorial of TexturePacker + Libgdx](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/tutorials/libgdx-physics)